# downgrade mvc version 5 to mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I realize  [this question has been asked by Crudler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079314/downgrading-asp-net-mvc-5-from-net-4-5-to-4-0) and [this one by Aaiam Litigoner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624143/downgrade-convert-mvc-4-to-mvc-3) regarding downgrading.

Our web hosting provider failed to tell me that MVC 5 projects are not able to be hosted with our package (even letting them know absolute specifics about the project I need hosted). Bottom line, it's a huge E-commerce website that I will be in shambles to have to redo from scratch based off MVC 4 framework.

I have tried uninstalling System.Mvc references and installing MVC 4 via Nuget Package Manager, but build errors are crazy and come by the thousands since most of the code I wrote is MVC 5 based.

Is there a simple fix to downgrade MVC versions without having to start a new project and copy every single file manually, such as a patch of some sort? There's 52 projects within one solution and that's just simply not an option.

**Other Specs:**

- Using Visual Studio 2015 Community
- .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: It would probably be simpler just to find a new hosting provider. Microsoft [officially no longer supports](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/) any version of .NET framework lower than 4.5.2 (except 3.5, but that is not helpful here). MVC 3 and 4 do not support 4.5, so downgrading is not advisable. That said, there is really nothing more that can be added that hasn't already been said in those two posts.

Comment: @NightOwl888, I had a feeling a reply like this was coming. And one that I was hoping to avoid. I just purchased my package with HostGator around 20 days ago so there's a chance I can get a full refund before our 45 day mark. We can upgrade our package to support MVC 5 which is the application I have (almost) fully developed. Although the upgrade is very costly. Thanks though.

Comment: More costly than fixing all of those build errors and potentially getting hacked down the line because there are no more updates to .NET 4?

Comment: in comparison to the ultimatum I'm currently in, no. I was just curious if there was a patch or at least some package that would fix build errors after wiping all MVC references and reinstalling MVC packages up to version 4. Most likely I'll have to bite the bullet and pay up. I appreciate the help though @NightOwl888